# Why does it work: background-position: top right -200px

Tags: css, background, responsive-design, offset, fluid-layout

I'm trying to use a single image as background in a *fluid layout / responsive design* to create a *fake sidebar column*.

Although the code in the title works just fine in Chrome (other browsers yet untested), I don't understand why. The [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp) do not document a use of 3 "parameters". (A German site served as reference at first, but I needed an English reference for this question. That's the first I came up with.)

I'm fine with the code working as long as it is cross-browser. I was going to test browser compatibility only once I'm satisfied with the design in Chrome.

However, when I tried to employ something like:

```
background-position: -200px right -200px;
```

and tried different variations, it just failed.

**Question:** I couldn't find any documentation on this markup in the first place... could this be a bug or is there a valid explanation? If it is valid, could somebody explain to me how I could go about this properly?

Comment: From
[w3c backround-position](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/background-position) 3 parameters seems meanless so maybe it's taking the first 2 params?

Comment: If that was the case, there shouldn't be any offset at all to the right. But as I said, that's working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accoding to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position_value), background-position takes in a position value, which can take in up to 4 values.

In your case, it should be equivalent to `background-position: top -200px right -200px`, which is a background image with position (-200, -200) at the top right corner of the element.

*Edit*:
As @Dvir mentioned in the comments, W3C is the actual specification that you can look at as well. I prefer MDN because it's more user-friendly while still being accurate and detailed.

Comment: You know, I tried that, but it didn't seem to be working. Just now I realized that it actually did work, it just didn't make any difference because it is repeated in y-direction anyways. So I have to figure out a different solution. Thanks anyways!